# Execute java class from php

Tags: java, php, ejb

I want to execute some java class for doing some bacground work,(have no any ui related task).like file read, write in a specific location. My main server side is done by php. I want to call these java program from php file. I study about Java/PHP Bridge. But i could not understand what i have to use like jse program(not suitable in server),jsp application (have no gui), or by a ejb. Please tell me what will be the best option to do that?

Comment: You could perhaps invoke the Java application like any command-line command in the PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a program in a couple of ways:

- [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
- [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
- [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)
- [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or the shell [execution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) (the backticks, ``)

Which one to use depends on what you want. You should study the above links and figure out which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exec()` function:

```
exec("java Main.class");
```

Comment: I try it keeping .java class file in a jse project and in same folder in php project but not work. @Jonan